# regex match number in parentheses (Firefox)

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have string like this:

```
(3) Request Inbox
```

Now I want to detect number `3` in parentheses. Pay attention just `3`. I write this regex in javascript but it doesn't work in Firefox.

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(?<=\()\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?=\))/g);
```

> Error in console: SyntaxError: invalid regexp group

[Demo link](https://regex101.com/r/eNOcvx/1)

Comment: If you just want to match the number, do you even need the lookahead? What about something as simple as: `/^\((\d+)\)/g` - it matches in group 1. Or do you mean, only the full match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a full match try this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(?=\d+\))\d+/g);
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your answer need more explanation about how the code works to be a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Positive lookbehind is not supported by most browsers so use an alternative way to get your answer.

Something like this,

```
var string = "somestring(12)";
var exp = /(?:\()(\d+)(?:\.\d+)?(?=\))/;
var mat = string.match(exp);

if(mat) {
    console.log(mat[1]);// second index
}
```

This should only give 12 as the answer

Comment: it has problem, please check it [https://regex101.com/r/eNOcvx/2](https://regex101.com/r/eNOcvx/2)

Comment: The first parenthesis is shown as 'matched' string but when you get the matched group it will come out as number only